# Geary stuck on messaging menu after uninstallation

Tags: unity, 16.04, messaging-menu, geary

I uninstalled Geary but for some reason it still shows in the Messaging Menu with a "No" symbol as an icon.  I tried restarting.

Under /usr/share/indicators/messages/applications there are only Pidgin and Thunderbird.

I don't understand why or how Geary is still showing in the menu.  I've attached a pic of the menu with the applications folder open as well.

[image: Geary]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself.  I installed dconf-editor

`sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`

And navigated to com > canonical > indicator > messages

There, you'll find a value called "applications".  Within this value are applications between the [ ] brackets separated by commas.  `geary.desktop` was here along with `thunderbird.desktop`.

So I changed

`[thunderbird.desktop,geary.desktop]`

to

`[thunderbird.desktop]`

And now the Geary menu item is gone.